# Compare two distinct groups of data with colors

Tags: color-scheme, grouped-list

I have three types of notes, User Note, System Note(, Communication Note(.

I have 3 Events. Each event has multiple notes of type User Note, System Note, Communication note.

I am trying to determine the best way to display with colors what the groupings are. I used Yellow for User Note, Green for communication, and purple for system. Then an event id label with different colors to signify groups. However it gets extremely lost in the noise. Does anyone have any tips for how to convey this information best?

[image: How it looks now]

Comment: Do the notes in your screenshot appear in chronological order? If not, what is the order? Are all three events represented in the screenshot? If so, how are they differentiated currently?

Comment: @Andy yes, chronologically from top left to bottom right. If you look really closely, the label colors are different, one is light blue, one is light green. For the last one, they are related events, it could be only 1 event showing, it could be as many as 12.

Answer (score 3):

Using color to tie similar objects together is better than nothing but can fail to get the job done for colorblind users.

If you can change the order of the notes consider explicitly tying the groups together as follows...

[image]

Comment: The gray blocks are the event ids?

Answer (score 2):

I would rethink the approach, instead of creating Groups, why don't you base everything in relations, that way it's scalable, also because I'm assuming this is about a same system so at the end of the day everything is related.  I would also avoid using long numeric ids and would include who is posting the note.  Here's a quick mockup:

[image]

Comment: I really like this answer. However the long numeric ID's must be incorporated. This is more of a working screen and it must be immediately obvious which event it is related to. Maybe a listboxish thing at the top to show blue is event 3042 and orange is 3192. Also, no event will have multiple colors, the note relates directly to the event.